# Import-DscResource cannot find the package cChoco

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-dsc

I am trying to write a DSC script that will be published into Azure Virtual machine. So far I have been able to accomplish basic things like enabling windows features and creating directories. But now I want to install chocolatey on azure virtual machine. So this is my script

```
configuration IIsAspNetInstall
{
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName cChoco
    node "localhost"
    {
        WindowsFeature IIS
        {
            Ensure="present"
            Name="web-server"
        }
        WindowsFeature InstallDotNet45
        {
            Name = "Web-Asp-Net45"
            Ensure = "Present"
        }
        WindowsFeature InstallIISConsole
        {
            Name = "Web-Mgmt-Console"
            Ensure = "Present"
        }
        File WebsiteFolderCreate 
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Type = "Directory"
            DestinationPath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AdventureWorks"
            Force = $true
        }
        cChocoInstaller installChoco 
        { 
            InstallDir = "C:\choco" 
        }
    }
}
```

On my local machine I am using PowerShell 5.0 and inside ISE I get red squiggly lines under `Import-DscResource` saying cannot find moduleName cChoco. I know it is a keyword and supposed to be valid inside Configuration section. When I do `Publish-AzureVMDscConfiguration` I get a parse error

```
+     Import-DscResource -ModuleName cChoco
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Could not find the module 'cChoco'.
```

Comment: Is module cChoco installed on the machine? Error message is pretty clear on what is the problem.

Comment: I thought Import-DscResource would import it but then I discovered that I can use Install-Module and install the module. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can bundle the module in the DSC package, either manually (by putting it in the a subfolder in the zip file) or by using the Publish-AzureVMDSCConfiguration cmdlets.  If the module is installed on the machine where you run the cmdlet, it will look at all the import module statements in your PS1 file and package them for you - once package, when you run the script on the destination machine, the module(s) will be installed automatically too...

Comment: I discovered what you said in one of the troubleshooting blog posts about DSC. I noticed cChoco was packaged.